# Cocoa NSTask help

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

I need a bit of help with NSTask. Also, I am new to Cocoa / Obj-C programming, so please bear with me. I am trying to make a directory. Then, remove it. So here is what I have so far:

```
NSLog (@"START");

NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/mkdir"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"/tmp/TEMP", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task setStandardError: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

NSLog (@"MKDIR");

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog (@"OUTPUT:\n%@", string);

[task release];
//EDIT: The following lines should be removed and [string release]; should be added.
[arguments release];
[pipe release];
[file release];
[data release];
```

My question is if the part towards the end about "release"-ing is correct? If not, can someone help me correct it? Also, if I wanted to do another NSTask of "rmdir", would I just do "task = [[NSTask alloc] init];" and so on for each variable I used or will I need to make new variables? THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no, you aren't managing memory correctly (hint: only `task` is correctly handled above).   [Read this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) as it explains all.

Secondly, there is no need to use an `NSTask` instance to make/delete a directory.  You should use `NSFileManager` instead;  again -- [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) explains all.

Comment: Actually, I was just using mkdir/rmdir as an example. I will be doing this for other commands, such as dd, dns-sd, asr, etc.